# How to declare a local variable that is a closure in swift

Tags: swift, ios8, closures

I want to declare a local variable which is of type closure how do I do that?

Comment: Just `var closure: ()->()`. Or if it's optional, `var closure: (() -> ())?`. Obviously, if it has parameters or return type, adjust accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var myClosure: (myParamaterTypes) -> myReturnTypes
```

eg:

```
var myClosure: (Int, Int) -> Int  // type is (Int, Int) -> Int
myClosure = {(integer01: Int, integer02: Int) -> Int in return integer01 + integer02}
```

Comment: Thank you! this is the right answer I was looking . Upvote my question if you find this question helpful :)